# Can I swap iPhone 13 Pro battery to iPhone 14 Battery?

Tags: iphone, battery

I watched some teardown videos of the iPhone 14 Pro, and they said the battery on the iPhone 14 Pro is identical to the one on the iPhone 13 Pro. Is it possible to exchange iPhone 13 Pro battery for iPhone 14 Pro battery?

Comment: Are you removing the battery from a brand new 14 and putting it into a 13; or taking a (used) battery from a 13, and putting it into a brand new 14? Either way -- why? If there's a problem with the 14's battery, take it back to the shop for a free fix, replacement or refund. If there's no problem with 14, enjoy your new phone. If you prefer the 13, then don't buy a 14; just get the battery replaced, if needed.

Comment: I am not exchanging at the moment. I am curious, however, since the iPhone 14 pro battery and iPhone 13 pro flex cable look the same.

Comment: Do you have some confusion between the iPhone 14 and the iPhone 14 Pro? Your history of edits suggest so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in the size of the battery between the iPhone 14 Pro and the iPhone 13 Pro. There is even the same flex cable between them that can be easily exchanged.

An [iPhone 14 Pro teardown](https://www.papernow.co.uk/iphone-14-pro-teardown/) shows that the battery has been replaced. Although I did not try to exchange myself.

If you are considering exchanging yourself, ask yourself whether it is really necessary. Although the shape of the batteries is the same, the capacity of the batteries is not. There is a significant improvement in battery performance and capacity in the iPhone 14 Pro.

Comment: OP was asking about the iPhone 14 not the iPhone 14 Pro.

Comment: In the description, he wrote about iPhone 14 Pro. Maybe he did a mistake in the title.